# Bold the last row in table

Tags: php, fpdf

How can I make the last row `Bold` in `fpdf`?

here is my code

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
            $cnt = 0;
                foreach ($row as $col) {
                    if($cnt < 1){
                        $this->Cell(9,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                    } elseif ($cnt < 2) {
                        $this->Cell(18,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                    } else {
                        $this->Cell(18,5, $col, 1, 0,'R'); 
                    }
                    $cnt++;
                }
              $this->Ln();
            }
        }
```

Updated Code : Added conditions for the rows until reach the last row.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
            $cnt = 0;
            if ($currentRow === $totalRows) {
                $this->SetFont('Arial','B'); 
                foreach ($row as $col) {
                    if($cnt < 1){
                        $this->Cell(9,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                    } elseif ($cnt < 2) {
                        $this->Cell(18,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                    } else {
                        $this->Cell(18,5, $col, 1, 0,'R'); 
                    }
                    $cnt++;
                }

            } else {
                $this->SetFont('Arial'); 
                foreach ($row as $col) {
                    if($cnt < 1){
                        $this->Cell(9,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                    } elseif ($cnt < 2) {
                        $this->Cell(18,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                    } else {
                        $this->Cell(18,5, $col, 1, 0,'R'); 
                    }
                    $cnt++;
                }
            }
            $currentRow++;
            $this->Ln();
        }
```

The sample code above creates the row and column my target is to make the last row bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) rows and then check if current processed row is the last one.

```
$totalRows = count($data);
$currentRow = 1;
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // (...)
    if ($currentRow === $totalRows) {
        // this is the last row
    }
    $currentRow++;
}
```

Here is the working code.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
                $cnt = 0;
                if ($currentRow === $totalRows) {
                    $this->SetFont('Arial','B'); 
                    foreach ($row as $col) {
                        if($cnt < 1){
                            $this->Cell(9,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                        } elseif ($cnt < 2) {
                            $this->Cell(18,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                        } else {
                            $this->Cell(18,5, $col, 1, 0,'R'); 
                        }
                        $cnt++;
                    }

                } else {
                    $this->SetFont('Arial'); 
                    foreach ($row as $col) {
                        if($cnt < 1){
                            $this->Cell(9,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                        } elseif ($cnt < 2) {
                            $this->Cell(18,5,$col,1,0,'C');
                        } else {
                            $this->Cell(18,5, $col, 1, 0,'R'); 
                        }
                        $cnt++;
                    }
                }
                $currentRow++;
                $this->Ln();
            }
```

Comment: Hi! Please see the code above the updated one try to make it but the last row did not turn to `bold`

Comment: nevermid i fixed it tysm